# Does Rust have syntax sugar for creating an array with an appended element?

Tags: rust

I have a 3-element array:

```
let color = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25];
```

I'd like to turn it into a 4-element array, which would be the 3-element array plus one appended element:

```
let color_with_alpha = [color[0], color[1], color[2], 1.0];
```

I know Rust has some cool syntax sugar for a lot of things; is there something for this? Something like:

```
let color_with_alpha = [color, 1.0];
```

I've read about the [`concat` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html) but that seems to only create string slices. I would imagine there's a vector-based solution but I don't require the dynamic sizing.

Comment: Why not just use `push`? If you need to keep the first vector, just use `clone()`, bind it to a variable, and then push to that. If you can't use `clone`, and can't consume `color`, then the odds are that this syntax sugar wouldn't work even if it was implemented. If dynamic resizing is an issue, `let color_with_alpha = Vec::with_capacity(color.len() + 1);`

Comment: @BHustus `color` is an [Array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html), not a [Vector](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

Comment: Wow, I actually forgot that Rust has standard arrays, hah. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such syntax.

It's always hard to *prove* a negative, but I've implemented a [parser of Rust code](https://github.com/shepmaster/fuzzy-pickles) and I've used Rust for over 3 years; I've never encountered any such syntax.

---

The closest I can imagine would be to implement a trait for array of various sizes. This is complicated because you cannot move out of non-`Copy` arrays. Since there's no generic integers, you'd have to implement this trait for every size of array you needed.

```
trait ArrayAppend<T> {
    type Output;
    fn append(self, val: T) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T: Copy> ArrayAppend<T> for [T; 3] {
    type Output = [T; 4];

    fn append(self, val: T) -> Self::Output {
        [self[0], self[1], self[2], val]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let color = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25];
    let color2 = color.append(1.0);
}
```

Comment: If I can ask these kinds a different way I'm open to your thoughts, but yeah, I guess that's kind of how these questions go :) Thanks for the insight.